# What PWM frequency should be used for a solid state relay (SSR)

Tags: relay, pwm, solid-state-relay

I am planning to use an [SSR (see product here)](https://www.amazon.de/diymore-V-380-SSR-40DA-DC-AC-Relais-Modul/dp/B08FWWRK2Y/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=5F06P3FQOB3Q&keywords=ssr%20relay&qid=1650110145&sprefix=ssr%20relay%2Caps%2C180&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyTU5OMVFQR0ZIV1RMJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwODY3NTc2U1YxR0k2UFJOUjRPJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAzNjA2NjMyVVFGM1RHRkdWWkpaJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==) to PID control the temperature of a heat bath.

According to the [SSR40-DA](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/SSR40DA.pdf) the response time is < 10ms so I would go for a PWM frequency that is well above, i.e. 10Hz or even 1Hz.

Can an SSR be used continuously for years at a PWM frequency of 1-10Hz?

Comment: It depends. Some years ago, I did hear a guy blogging that he used a cheapy SSR to control heater for perhaps 10 years continuously.  He also mentioned the SSR once fried, but not causing a fire. I think cheapy electromagnetic relays are might not more reliable, but should be safer, not causing any fire, because it opens if breaks down.

Comment: In addition to estimating how much time it takes to make a 1°C temp rise, you can also estimate the thermal "momentum" - essentially how much your temp will keep rising. After you turn the power off.  But that can gets a bit complicated if your heater element's heat capacity  is a big percent of the water heat capacity.  Heat capacity is the energy needed to heat the device or water a 1°C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most PWM controllers allow 1024 (10-bit) or 256 (8-bit) different levels. So, if you are using 1Hz update frequency and 1% duty cycle or less (10/1024) or (2/256), you'll be on for a period less, your switching may be a bit messed up. Even up to 10% duty cycle, a lot of your on cycle will be muffled by switching.  Same for duty cycles above 90%.

You could use software to avoid switching inside of these windows.

I'd use even longer, like 0.1Hz and bit-bang the PWM if your microcontroller doesn't allow hardware PWM frequencies that low.  Or just give up PWM and use some fuzzy logic in place of the PID. Temp control is pretty easy in thermostat mode (on/off). You can also estimate time to full power to make a 1°C change and integrate that into your fuzzy logic. Keep updating the controllers estimate of how long it take to make a 1°C change as water evaporates from the bath (or refilled).

Comment: Thanks @GT Electronics I will go for a bang-bang controller and estimate the time/energy it needs to heat up a certain volume of water for a certain temperature.

Answer (score 4):

The SSR40-DA switches on or off at zero-crossings of the AC supply, so it can't be used for PWM control with on or off times less than a half-cycle of the AC supply.

Comment: +1 In fact, if zero crossing detection is made available to the uC too, considering the slow nature of the load, dozens or hundreds of power levels can be achieved on the basis of counting half-cycles on and off. With the added benefit of switching on/off at "zero" current.